# React.js: How to import dynamically redux action

Tags: reactjs, redux

Is there any solution to import dynamically below redux action and use it?

```
import { set } from 'actions/formula-form';
```

Solved!:

```
const action = require('actions/' + props.action);
 dispatch(action.set({ formulaId: dataItem.id }));
  };
```

Comment: What do you mean by dynamically?

Comment: @Deep I make a component that get a prop as action and I want load this action dynamically and set state of redux inside the component.

Comment: Why its related to dynamically import?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
import { set } from 'actions/formula-form';
import { connect } from "react-redux";
...

component() {
...
this.props.getProps(value);
...
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  getProps: state.formula-form.data,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  set,
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(DashBoard);
```

Comment: @thanks but I used this code and my problem 
`const action = require('actions/' + props.action);`